# understanding Exponent of $y= a^{mx}$

Tags: calculus

Why does $y=a^{mx}$ imply $y=e^{log(a)\cdot mx}?$

Comment: Have a look at the definition of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm Supposing you mean $\log(a)$ as natural logarithm.

Comment: It really boils down to the definition, as ulead86 said-that and the relationship between the base e exponential and the exponential of arbitrary real base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $a=e^{\log(a)}$, with $\log$ the natural logarithm, which is the inverse of an $e$-power.

Thus, $y=a^{mx} = (e^{\log(a)})^{mx} = e^{ \log(a) mx }$, where the last equality hold because in general $(b^c)^d = b^{cd}$ (just think of what a power actually means)

Comment: Thank you very much. that cleared my doubt

Answer (score 0):

It is from exponents rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$. then:
$$y=a^{mx}=(e^{log(a)})^{mx}=e^{mxlog(a)}$$